# How to release event id from Google calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have an event with a particular id (e.g. "17448") and I deleted it and then removed from a trash. The problem is I can't use the same event id again. I can't create event, update or delete.

I always getting "Error":

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

But still can use "get" method and I getting this:

```
{'end': {'date': '2000-01-02'},
 'etag': '"2980807593935000"',
 'iCalUID': '17448@google.com',
 'id': '17448',
 'kind': 'calendar#event',
 'start': {'date': '2000-01-01'},
 'status': 'cancelled',
 'transparency': 'transparent',
 'updated': '2017-03-27T07:32:07.111Z'}
```

So, is a way to release the event id for reuse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to *release* a Calendar `eventId`.

The `eventId` is a unique identifier for each Calendar event and is expected to be kept that way in order to prevent *collision* (i.e. *mix-ups*) in records and/or logs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Do mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the *check mark* on the left side of the answer so that your post will be properly tagged. Cheers! :)

Comment: Yeah, sure. Forgot about that.

Comment: @AL: To clarify, it seems that deleting an Event from G Cal does not nullify any of the data in the Event apart from -- I'm guessing here -- some setting that indicates that it is published on G Cal, and that's why functions like getEventById() will still work given the event ID even after the event is deleted? I've been very confused and now I think I understand. Do I have this right?

Comment: Hi @AtiqZabinski Sorry. It's been a while since I dabbled with Google Calendar, so I'm not entirely confident I could confirm your clarification. Cheers!

Comment: Answering my own question: yes. More info at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48122824/google-apps-script-how-to-check-if-a-calendar-event-has-been-marked-as-deleted