# Google Apps Script: How to check if a calendar event has been marked as deleted manually

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I've written a Google Apps Script which adds events kept in a spreadsheet to a google calendar. Each event stores the calendar event's ID so that it can update it if the event in the spreadsheet gets modified. The event can still be deleted manually in the calendar so I would like the script to detect this and recreate the event. Unfortunately, I cannot simply check for `null` when calling `getEventById(...)` on a [`calendar`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar) object because even when deleted, this function seems to be returning a valid `calendar` object.

The [`CalendarEvent`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event) API documentation doesn't seem to point to a way to check if the event has been deleted via the UI/manually. Is there a way of accessing this property through the Google Apps API?

Even permanently deleting trashed events does not fix the problem, although it then prevents modifications to the returned `event` object.

What can I use to check if the event (which still exists) has been "deleted"? The only thing I can think might be of use is the `get/setTag()` methods for the `CalendarEvent` object.

Alternatively, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43195549/google-apps-script-retrieve-deleted-calendar-events) question looks similar, but it feels like there should be a better way than searching through a list of trashed events, and I'm not sure this would get around the issue of having ID strings return valid events that have been "permanently" deleted.

#### Example

```js
var calendarId = "abc123@group.calendar.google.com"
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

var event = calendar.createEvent(...);

// Event is then deleted manually in calendar but 
// ID has been saved in spreadsheet (or elsewhere)

if (calendar.getEventById("the-deleted-event-id") == null) {
    // Create the event (This is never reached)
} else {
    // Update the event
}
```

Comment: Alghough I had commented at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43195549/google-apps-script-retrieve-deleted-calendar-events), how about cheking the event status? If the event has deleted, the status returns ``cancelled``. If the event is existing, the status returns ``confirmed``. If you want the sample script, feel free to tell me. If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: So you did, Thanks! This pointed me toward the `Event.get` method which I believe should return the response for a specific event ID which would remove the need for searching through the response manually.

Answer (score 2):

I have spent quite a time solving this and I cant udnerstand why there is no better way how to solve it, directly by CalendarApp.
What you need is this:

```
var eventId = "5qif5n15v46c0jt5gq20a39dqu@google.com".split("@")[0];
if(Calendar.Events.get("yourCalendarId", eventId).status === "cancelled")
        CODE://what to do if event was deleted (manually)
```

Notes:

1. As API v3.0 uses as eventid only the part before @, so you need
   to split (strip rest)
2. You need Calendar API v3.0 first activate.

You will find more info about in this question: [Checking a Google Calendar Event's Existence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48155896/checking-a-google-calendar-events-existence)

Answer (score 2):

I found that the best way to do this is to check whether the [event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event) in question is included when asking the [calendar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar) for events during the time period of event in question:

```
var event = calendar.getEventById(eventId);
var events = calendar.getEvents(event.getStartTime(),event.getEndTime());
var isEventDeleted = events.some((event) => event.getId() == eventId);
```

Methods used:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#getEventById(String)
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#geteventsstarttime,-endtime
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getstarttime
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getendtime
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: You checked for event existence instead of deletion in the last line of your code.  
The correct check should be that the ID of all elements is different from the event in question, by `.every()` method:  
`var isEventDeleted = events.every((event) => event.getId() != eventId);`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to search only events that have not yet been deleted, which will cause deleted events to not be found.

```js
let result = Calendar.Events.list(<Calendar_ID>, {showDeleted: false});
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the Simpler Way is check if the Return is null or Not.
Null = event not found

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#geteventbyidicalid

CalendarEvent — the event with the given ID, or null if the event doesn't exist or the user cannot access it.