# Checking a Google Calendar Event's Existence

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have a very basic problem within my whole code which became a head-ache for a couple of days. I have made an extensive research on this issue however couldn't be able to find an exact solution (*or I have missed the one's that I might have found*). Here it is:

I have a spreadsheet, where I log in Google Calendar events with their properties including the id of the event. Sometimes, I clean up the Google Calendar manually and just want to run a code which checks the events existence in the calendar and if not delete the row. My code is:

```
function cleanCal(calid, eventid) {
  var calid = 'my calendar id';
  var eventid = 'event id';
  var event = CalendarApp.getOwnedCalendarById(calid).getEventById(eventid);

  if (event) {
    event.deleteEvent();
    // clean-up sheet
  } else {
    // clean-up sheet
  }
}
```

Basically if the event is in the calendar, the code shall delete it first and then clean the sheet, if it's not there, it should clean the sheet only. However, when the code is executed, though the calendar event is not there, the if statement returns true and raises an error when trying to delete the event as it's actually not there. I haven't been able to find out the reason, how and why the **event** object return **true** though the event is not existing. Where am I doing wrong?? Thanks for replying and any help is really appreciated.

**[EDIT]**
This is the code that I use to check events existence with Calendar API v3

```
function verifyCalendarEvent_OLD(calid, eventid) {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calid)
  var exists = true;
  var response = Calendar.Events.list(
  calid, {
    showDeleted: true,
    fields: "items(id,status,summary)"
    }
  );

  for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
    if (response.items[i].id == eventid.split("@")[0] && response.items[i].status == "cancelled") {
      exists = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return exists;
}
```

Comment: Posted what I think is the ideal solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62614117/5488127

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this answer?

### Modification points :

For example, if there is no event of the event ID, `CalendarApp.getOwnedCalendarById(calid).getEventById(eventid)` returns `null`. When this is evaluated by `if`, that is used as `false`.

So I thought that you might try to retrieve the event which has already been removed. Because at Google Calendar, even if the event is removed, the event ID is remained. So although there is no event for the event ID, `if (event) {}` in your script returns `true`. I confirmed that `CalendarApp.getOwnedCalendarById(calid).getEventById(eventid)` retrieves the removed events. For this situation, you can know whether the event is removed by confirming the event status.

- When the event status is **confirmed**, it indicates that the event is still not removed.
- When the event status is **cancelled**, it indicates that the event has already been removed.

### Preparation to use this modified sample script :

When you use this modified script, please enable Calendar API at Advanced Google Services and API console.

#### Enable Calendar API v3 at Advanced Google Services

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Advanced Google Services
  - Turn on Calendar API v3

#### [Enable Calendar API at API console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/calendar-json.googleapis.com/?q=calendar)

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Cloud Platform project
  - View API console
  - At Getting started, click Enable APIs and get credentials like keys.
  - At left side, click Library.
  - At Search for APIs & services, input "Calendar". And click Calendar API.
  - Click Enable button.
  - If API has already been enabled, please don't turn off.
  - **When you run this script, if an error occurs, you might be required to wait few minutes until the API is enabled.**

### Modified script :

```
function cleanCal(calid, eventid) {
  var calid = 'my calendar id';
  var eventid = 'event id';
  var status = Calendar.Events.get(calid, eventid).status; // Added

  if (status == "confirmed") { // Modified
    var event = CalendarApp.getOwnedCalendarById(calid).getEventById(eventid); // Added
    event.deleteEvent();
    // clean-up sheet
  } else {
    // clean-up sheet
  }
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

In my environment, the events removed by manual and script can be retrieved as `status=cancelled`. Since I didn't know your situation, I prepared a sample script. This sample script is a simple flow.

1. Create new event.
2. Delete the created event.
3. Confirm the deleted event.

   - Here, your additional script was used.

#### Sample script :

```
function deleteeventa() {
  // Create new event
  var calid = 'my calendar id';
  var c = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calid);
  var r = c.createEvent("sample event for deleting", new Date(2018,0,11,00,00), new Date(2018,0,11,01,00));

  // Delete the created new event
  var eventid = r.getId().split('@')[0];
  var event = c.getEventById(eventid);
  event.deleteEvent();

  // Your additional script
  var exists = true;
  var response = Calendar.Events.list(
  calid, {
    showDeleted: true,
    fields: "items(id,status,summary)"
    }
  );
  for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
    if (response.items[i].id == eventid && response.items[i].status == "cancelled") {
      exists = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  Logger.log("%s, %s, %s", r.getTitle(), r.getId(), exists)
}
```

#### Result :

```
sample event for deleting, #####@google.com, false
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Tanaike. It's smart idea to use Calendar API v3 instead of CalendarApp Services when checking the events I believe. As far as I have understood, you first get the **status** of the event with Calendar API and then temporarily add that event and delete it back immediately. But the cons to this technique is Calendar API will return a **null** or **undefined** status for an event which is removed with script.

Comment: For example for a same Event ID where CalendarApp returns true value, Calendar API does not return that event's id in the items list when I check it where it becomes not possible to read its status.

Comment: @Levent Kulacoglu I'm sorry for the inconvenience and for my incomplete answer. For this comment ``For example for a same Event ID where CalendarApp returns true value, Calendar API does not return that event's id in the items list...``, do you try to retrieve the event ID with the status of "cancelled" using ``Calendar.Events.list()``? If it's so, ``showDeleted: true`` is required to retrieve the event ID. Can you show me your current script? By knowing your current situation, I will be able to think of the solution. If you can show your current script, please add it to your question.

Comment: I have provided my code in my question body. As you can see there I'm already showDeleted: true property in the payload. When you retrieve the Calendar.Events.list(), it shows the id of the events if and only if you had removed the events from Google Calendar manually. However, if you remove an event with Google Apps Script, it does not bring that id anymore in the list. On the contrary CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calid).getEventById(eventid) still returns **true** value. Either it's a weird situation or I'm doing a stupid eval.

Comment: @Levent Kulacoglu Thank you for your additional information. And I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. Your replies enlightened my path thru the solution. I'm posting my solution as a reply to my Q, so that other users can benefit out of it. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Levent Kulacoglu Welcome. I'm glad your problem was solved. I could study from your question. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Tanaike Recently Google have changed the behaviour such that an EventID *can* be utterly obliterated. Previously it was just marked with "cancelled", which showed as struckthrough on the calendar and subscriptions. This was a backwards step for Google, as they lost the ability to cancel an event - it now deletes completely which can lead people to think that it has been moved in the schedule or that there is a glitch. Better to confirm something as cancelled than simply make it vanish!

Comment: @TRT 1968 Thank you for your additional information. I think that it will be useful for other users. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Following [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike)'s great help, I have come up with this code snippet which - *as far as I have tested* - works fine for now. Hope it might be helpful for other users. Here is the code fragment:

```
function verifyCalendarEvent(calid, eventid) {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calid)
  eventid = eventid.split("@")[0];
  var exists = true;
  var eventIds = [];
  var eventStats = [];

  var response = Calendar.Events.list(
  calid, {
    showDeleted: true,
    fields: "items(id,status,summary)"
    }
  );

  for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
    eventIds.push(response.items[i].id);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
    eventStats.push(response.items[i].status);
  }

  if (eventIds.indexOf(eventid) > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < eventIds.length; i++) {
      if (eventIds[i] == eventid && eventStats[i] == "cancelled") {
        exists = false;
      }
    }
  } else {
    exists = false;
  }
  Logger.log("Calendar Event ["+eventid+"] exists? >> "+exists);
  return exists;
}
```